# Repeatable read implementation in MySql server side?

Tags: mysql

I understand what Repeatable Read Transaction Isolation Level means.

During a repeatable read transaction, whatever transactions have committed data after my transaction has started won't be seen by my transaction.

However I am having a tough time understanding how is it actually implemented at sql server side. Is it that at the start of every transaction a snapshot of the database is taken and set aside for that particular transaction ?

If that is so, then the amount of memory resource would be huge in case if multiple repeatable read transactions are started at any point of time ?

Also can someone throw light on the role of Shared/Exclusive lock role in repeatable read 
?

Comment: MySQL is open source, so you can look up.

Comment: Some info here https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/introduction_to_transaction_locks_in

Comment: In case of repeatable read it says that it does not release shared lock till the end of transaction. On what is the shared lock taken? Lets say there are 10 rows in table. is the shared lock taken on each row ? and if the lock is taken, how is it possible for any other transaction to commit before this transaction is completed ?

Answer (score 0):

I seek the same answer for a while, and after some search work, I think it basically implemented by using [`MVCC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)(`Snapshot Read`) + `GAP LOCK` + `NEXT KEY LOCK`.

I am not quite sure I understand it correctly, but I think some keyword may help in further search work.

By the way, if anyone understand Chinese very well, here are some good explanation written in Chinese:

http://hedengcheng.com/?p=771
https://www.cnblogs.com/kismetv/p/10331633.html